# Evento se dispara incluso si no se cumple cierta condición

Tags: javascript

Puse un `addEventListener` a un botón e hice una variable para verificar cuándo se apretaba. Al `addEventListener` lo puse dentro de una condición para que solo se apriete una vez, pero no funcionó. Cada que le doy click funciona, aunque la condición no se está cumpliendo. Anexo mi código a continuación.

```js
var boton = document.getElementById("boton");
var texto = document.getElementById("texto");
var apretado = false; //esta variable es para verificar si dieron click al botón

if (apretado == false) //esta condiciónes para que solo se pueda dar click al botón una vez, y solo se aplique la función escribir una vez pero no funciona.
{
  boton.addEventListener("click", escribir);
}

function escribir() {
  texto.innerHTML += "Funciona <br>";
  apretado = true;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Botón" id="boton">
<p id="texto"> </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías hacer algo así:

```
if(apretado == false) //esta condiciónes para que solo se pueda dar click al botón una vez, y solo se aplique la función escribir una vez pero no funciona.
{
  boton.addEventListener("click", escribir);
}

function escribir ()
{
  texto.innerHTML += "Funciona <br>";
  boton.removeEventListener("click", escribir) //Aquí removemos la escucha del evento
  apretado = true;
}
```

Así como le haces un addEventListener, cuando deseas cancelar la escucha del evento debes hacer un removeEventListener. Sino este queda escuchando por más que esté el if.

---

Podrías incluso remover el if y la variable apretado e incluso deshabilitar el botón y hacer algo así:

Código completo:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Evento</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Botón" id="boton" />
    <p id="texto"></p>
    <script>
      var boton = document.getElementById("boton");
      var texto = document.getElementById("texto");

      boton.addEventListener("click", escribir);

      function escribir() {
        texto.innerHTML += "Funciona <br>";
        boton.removeEventListener("click", escribir);
        boton.disabled = true;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

El addEventListener se inicia al cargar el script, entonces no debes hacer más nada, solo cuando presionas el botón haces el remove del listener.

Te dejo documentación, por si deseas leer al respecto:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Answer (score 0):

Lo único que tienes que realizar en tu ejemplo es quitar el eventListener, con [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener), ya que como esta activo desde un inicio, mientras no lo retires, seguirá funcionando.

```
boton.removeEventListener("click", escribir);
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Evento</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <input type = "button" value = "Botón" id= "boton">
     <p id = "texto"> </p>
   <script>

var boton = document.getElementById("boton");
var texto = document.getElementById ("texto");
var apretado = false; //esta variable es para verificar si dieron click al botón

if(apretado == false) //esta condiciónes para que solo se pueda dar click al botón una vez, y solo se aplique la función escribir una vez pero no funciona.
{
  boton.addEventListener("click", escribir);
}

function escribir ()
{
  texto.innerHTML += "Funciona <br>";
  apretado = true;
  boton.removeEventListener("click", escribir);
}

   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```